# Are these MySQL queries efficient?

Tags: mysql, performance

It took me quite a while to learn how to deal with timestamps in MySQL and I think I accomplished my goals, but I want to double-check two things:

1) Are these doing what I expect

2) Are there faster replacements for these queries / functions

Today

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM log WHERE DATE(datet) = DATE(NOW())
```

This Week

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM log WHERE YEARWEEK(NOW()) = YEARWEEK(datet)
```

Last Week

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM log WHERE YEARWEEK(datet) = YEARWEEK(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK))
```

This Month

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM log WHERE datet > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Last Month

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM log WHERE datet > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND datet < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Answer (score 10):

The queries where you have your `datet` column wrapped within a function (e.g. `DATE()`, `YEARWEEK()`) are not efficient due to the fact that MySQL has to evaluate the output of the function for each row in your table. This renders the query as non-sargable (i.e. not able to utilize indexes on the `datet` column).

It appears you want to select the count of all records within a particular timeframe. To do this, you have to use `>=`, not `=`. Also, there is a difference between "*this month*" and "*within one month*". I'm assuming you want the former (i.e. if say today was August 3rd, you'd only want records within August, and not from July 3rd, and same thing for week, etc...).

Assuming `datet` is a `DATETIME`/`TIMESTAMP` column and the values of the column will never be "in the future", you can rewrite your queries like so (each of which can utilize an index on the `datet` column):

```
-- Today
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM   log 
WHERE  datet >= CURDATE()
```

---

```
-- This Week
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM log 
WHERE datet >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL CASE WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) WHEN 6 THEN -1 ELSE WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) END + 1 DAY
```

---

```
-- Last Week
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM log 
WHERE datet >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL CASE WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) WHEN 6 THEN -1 ELSE WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) END + 1 DAY) - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
      AND
      datet < CURDATE() - INTERVAL CASE WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) WHEN 6 THEN -1 ELSE WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) END + 1 DAY
```

---

```
-- This Month
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM   log 
WHERE  datet >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()) - 1 DAY
```

---

```
 -- Last Month
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM log 
WHERE datet >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()) - 1 DAY) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
      AND 
      datet < CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()) - 1 DAY
```

---

```
-- This Year
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM   log 
WHERE  datet >= MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1)
```

Comment: Wow.... "non-sargable"  I'm in way over my head, lol.  Thanks, that is exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding this: `CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()) - 1 DAY`

Comment: @ColeTarbet Basically you can get the date of the first day of the month of any date by doing (current date - [current day of month - 1] days). So if today was August 23rd, `23 - (23-1) days = aug. 1`. August 1st: `1 - (1-1) days = aug. 1`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it's faster, but here's some alternatives :

This Month

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM log WHERE MONTH(datet) = MONTH(NOW())
```

Last Month

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM log WHERE MONTH(datet) = (MONTH(NOW()) - 1)
```

Comment: These 'alternatives' are much less efficient and even incorrect as they will include previous years.